# How to use G Suite Email Audit API with google-api-python-client?

Tags: python, api, audit, google-api-python-client, google-workspace

I want to get a list (subject, datetime, sender) of sent email from a specific user using `google-api-python-client`.

I found the [G Suite Email Audit API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/) but unfortunately there aren't any python examples.

Is this even possible with `google-api-python-client`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [G Suite Email Audit API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/) is one of the older APIs that still uses the [Google Data API protocol](https://developers.google.com/gdata/). This protocol is not supported by the google-api-python-client, but you have to use instead the [gdata-python-client](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client). This library is old and Google is not updating it anymore:

- it only works with Python 2.x
- to perform OAuth2 authentication you need to integrate it with the [oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/) library

Here is a sample on how to use it:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse

import gdata.apps.audit.service
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = ['https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/',]

# be sure to update with the correct user
ID = 'user@domain.com'

store = file.Storage('email-audit{}.json'.format(ID))
creds = store.get()

# client_id.json is the client_id file generated from the developer console project
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
    flags.auth_host_port = [8010, 8020]
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)

access_token, expires_in = creds.get_access_token()

gd_client = gdata.apps.audit.service.AuditService(domain=ID.split('@')[1])
gd_client.additional_headers[u'Authorization'] = u'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token)

monitors = gd_client.getEmailMonitors(ID.split('@')[0])

print(monitors)
```

If you want the original sample from Google, you can find it [here](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/blob/master/samples/apps/email_audit_email_monitoring.py). It is much more complex than mine and I doubt it will work as it is not performing OAuth2 authentication; use it as a reference.